# Update listener on maven repository managed by Nexus

Tags: maven, plugins, repository, nexus

We are using maven as build technology and nexus as repository manager. I would like to know what was just uploaded to repository and to do some actions after it's repository update is finished. How I can do this?

Write listener which is verifying file system and compare the difference? How I could then know the state if artifact is deployed and the uploading process is finished? Perhaps you know some other solutions?

All repositories I need resides on Linux.

Update, guys, I just saw that there are nexus plugins that can be used for this. Do you know how to get update event within nexus plugin?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nexus supports a whole number of different integrations that offer you different options. They are

- script against its REST API to access Nexus functionality from outside
- listen to the RSS feed events from outside
- write a plugin to work within Nexus and expands its functionality and/or user interface

In your case you can just subscribe to the system feed that contains the events you are interested in. In your case it might be "New Deployed Artifacts in All Repositories" available e.g. at `http://yournexusserver:8081/nexus/service/local/feeds/recentlyDeployedArtifacts`

Just monitor that feed with some script or other integration system that can poll it regularly and then perform whatever action you want.

If you want you can of course turn it around and write a Nexus plugin that listens to the events via internal API's and then triggers an action from Nexus. Choose whatever works easier for you in terms of implementation..

Check out the system feeds via Repositories - System Feeds[image]

Comment: Manfred, thank you for reply. It looks interesting. Do you know how I can listen RSS feed events from outside, perhaps you can have some samples?

Comment: It all depends on the tool you want to use. Things like Nagios or so can do that. Basically you have something polling and parsing the feed at regular intervals.

Comment: Manfred, thank you. I'm not going to use 3party tools and I was thinking that you could tell me what Sonatype Nexus is already offering to read these data files. It looks I almost found solution with RepositoryItemEventStoreCreate event but your answer is also useful.

Comment: Listening to that event in your own plugin is a good solution if you want to/can trigger whatever action you need performed from Nexus.

Answer (score 1):

To further elaborate on Manfred's answer, have a look at the virus scan example plugin here:

https://github.com/sonatype/nexus-example-plugins/

It's pretty close to what you want. Be sure to check out the nexus-2.3.x branch, the master is only buildable against 2.4-SNAPSHOT.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a continuous integration (CI) server, you could have a post build/deployment task that does the sort of notification you seem to be interested in.

I haven't dug around the Nexus OSS API much, but maybe you could check their IRC channels as well (#maven / #nexus on irc.codehaus.org).

Comment: thank you for reply. I was already thinking about adding it as post deployment step to CI but potentially we could have several CIs and I want to control what is coming to repository and listeners and implementing some extension point would match better here but I didn't find yet anything on Nexus side.

Comment: Maybe you could further explain your use case in the question.

Comment: carlspring, the case itlsef is simple, what I want is to start some script if I see thats some artifacts are added to repository. The solution as I see is to listen repository or nexus for uploading new artifacts.

Comment: No. The simplest solution is to have your CI as the only one who can deploy artifacts. This way you can always add a post build task that triggers the script you would like.

Comment: carlspring, what you would do if you have several CIs across the world and even inside of one office you could have several CIs for some historical reasons? You would need to update several places and I would prefer to have single place for change instead of having several ones. What do you think?